# too many re re-renders error on remove todo

Tags: reactjs

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./style.css";

function App() {
  const [movieData, setMovieData] = useState();
  const [directorData, setDirectorData] = useState();
  const [listData, setListData] = useState([]);

  const submitHandler = () => {
    setListData([
      ...listData,
      {
        movie: movieData,
        director: directorData,
      },
    ]);
    setMovieData("");
    setDirectorData("");
  };
  const removeHandler = (id) => {
    const newlist = listData.filter((remId) => {
      return remId !== id;
    });
    setListData(newlist)
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>
        <h1>Todo App</h1>
      </div>
      <div className="form">
        <div>
          <label>Movie</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="type items"
            value={movieData}
            onChange={(e) => setMovieData(e.target.value)}
          />
        </div>
        <div>
          <label>Director</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="type items"
            value={directorData}
            onChange={(e) => setDirectorData(e.target.value)}
          />
        </div>
        <div>
          <button onClick={submitHandler}>Submit</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
        {listData.map((item, index) => {
          return (
            <li key={index}>
              <span>{item.movie}</span>, <span>{item.director}</span>{" "}
              <span style={{ marginLeft: "2rem" }}>
                <button onClick={removeHandler(index)} style={{ color: "red" }}>
                  X
                </button>
              </span>
            </li>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

As soon as I added removeHandler, I am getting too many renders onSubmit. It's working fine once I remove removeHandler.

Is there any other method to remove items from the list apart from filter and splice(just mention the function name)?

I have even tried using useEffect but the same problem persists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change to `onClick={() => removeHandler(index)}`

and you also have to remove 'return' in your array.filter

```
      remId !== id;
    });
```

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/inspiring-framework-p5hp9y?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you're not passing an arrow function to onClick.
You're writing `onClick={removeHandler(index)}` instead of `onClick={() => removeHandler(index)}`.

It's because `functionName(param)` syntax is generally used to call functions so when you write that, it causes infinite renders.

Answer (score 0):

use this function some new changes

```js
const removeHandler = (id) => { const newlist = [...listData];
newlist.splice(id, 1); setListData(newlist); };
```

and change onclick event

```js
onClick={() => removeHandler(index)}
```